# Regular expression for numbers that dont start with dot

Tags: regex

I'm searching a regular expression that match just numbers that dont start with a '.' 
for example:

> .5 **not ok**
>
> 3. **ok**
>
> 4  **ok**
>
> 3.0 **ok**
>
> 6.45 **ok**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this pattern:

```
^[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*$
```

This pattern is designed to check a field, so it uses anchors `^` and `$`. If available, it is better to replace them with `\A` and `\z` since `$` may also match the end of the last line followed by a last newline, and for semantic reasons.

If you need to find these numbers in a larger string, you need to replace the anchors with something else:

with [lookarounds](http://regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) (if they are available in your regex flavor):

```
(?<![0-9.])[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*(?![0-9.])
```

with the help of a capture group (if not):

```
(?:^|[^0-9.])([0-9]+\.?[0-9]*)(?:$|[^0-9.])
```

*(then you need to extract the content of the capture group 1 to have the number)*

Note: you can write the last pattern in a basic syntax (to be used with sed for example):

```
\(^\|[^0-9.]\)\([0-9][0-9]*\.\?[0-9]*\)\($\|[^0-9.]\)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
^\d+(?:\.\d*)?$
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/aQ3zJ3/8

Comment: I deleted mine. Since yours came earlier.